# Session::forget() return an error Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my Laravel project, I am using `Session::forget("job-success")` to destroy particular session. However, it returns error stating "Unexpected token".

Code:

```
@if (Session::get('alert-danger') || Session::get('alert-success'))
<script>
    @if(Session::get('job-success'))
        show_notification("success","{{ Session::get('alert-success') }}");
        //Session::forget('job-success');
    @endif 
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: `key` is not a variable, you're missing the `$` prefix, like `$key`

Comment: I am using like Session::forget("alert-success").

Comment: "Unexpected token" sounds more like a javascript error. You're going to need to add more details and more code.

Comment: ohh I got it. session:forget() is in javascript code .thanks @patricus

Comment: The code you've shown will actually output the text `Session::forget('job-success')`, and that will be executed by javascript. That is causing your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting PHP code inside your javascript `<script>` tags. Javascript doesn't understand `Session::forget('job-success');`, so you're getting a javascript error.

You need to execute the PHP code in PHP, not javascript. Either use `<?php Session::forget('job-success'); ?>`, or `{{ Session::forget('job-success'); }}` (`forget()` returns void, so that will attempt to echo nothing).